# Are use statements imported from extended classes?

Tags: php

Let's say there's a base class:

```
use Test\Class;

class Base {

}
```

and then I extend that class:

```
class Child extends Base {

}
```

Is the imported class `Test\Class` from the base class automatically usable in the child? Or do I need to import it again to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the imported class Test\Class from the base class automatically
>   usable in the child? Or do I need to import it again to use it?

Depends if they are under the same namespace.
So in case they are:

```
namespace Test\Class;

class Base {}

// It's okay - This class can be in another file as well    
class Child extends Base {}
```

In case they are under different namespace, then use you have to import a class using `use` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying namespaces don't autoload anything. This is the job for auto-loader. If auto-loader finds the class, everything will work. Otherwise, `class not found` will be issued